# Page files disapear after failed publishing

Tags: publishing, deployer

I have two live servers with there own publisher and incoming directories. Most of the time there is no issue when publishing, although sometimes the HTTP IIS deployer instance is not available. If this is the case, the publishing fails as expected. The problem I am having is that the aspx page file that was supposed to be republished, is now gone. Is this standard behavior? Could it be that the roll-back not work anymore when the IIS deployer goes offline? Does the ASPX file normally get overwritten, or is it deleted before the new file is placed?

P.S. We do use a deployer extention that edits the file that is being published. But this happens in the first step after the ZIP file is unpacked and ready to be deployed.

Comment: Are you sure your publishing to the same location?
Can you run it without the extension to check if that is causing the issue?
Did you publish not unpublish?

Comment: If the Deployer is not available, it cannot handle deployment, so your files can not be touched. What you describe seems more like the Deployer failed during deployment, which sounds like a scenario which will always lead to strange results. Can you check to find more info, is the deployer extension executed for example, then your Deployer was active and available?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply

@GraemeWigglesworth the pages won't be valid if the deployer extention isn't run. The pages where published, but some of them faild in the process.

@I think the deployer is failing because there is a big load on the server (IIS) which will cause the deployer to time out. But i will try to add more logging to see what is going on.

I guess the only thing i need to know is is a file is removed before a new one is placed, or that a file is overwritten by the deployer.